# Wordpress error where comments usually display

Tags: wordpress

I have turned off comments in the screen options on my wordpress website but now I am receiving this error where the comments box used to be:

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'custom_comment' not found or invalid function name in /home/website/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 1335

I have no idea what is causing this problem. I've found the only way to get rid of it is to remove the comments from the loop-post-single.php file. However, I don't want to do this as i do want to allow comments in the future. Now when I turn comments on in the screen options, I still get the same error. I have checked the comment-template.php file and changed the function name to 'custom-comment' It removes the error but the comments no longer work correctly.

I have another file called theme-comments.php. This file has a custom-comment functon. Is there supposed to be a way that the two files are linked?

Any help would be so great

Comment: You mean when you uncheck comments from your screen options in your wp-admin, something somehow is affecting the front end of your website?  What theme are you using?  Are you talking about within your admin when you're trying to add a post?

Answer (score 1):

please first check your comment.php on your theme folder where there might be code like

```
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'xxxx_comment' ) );
```

change it to

```
wp_list_comments();
```

hope this one will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont have one exactly like that. I have the following.

     <?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=75&callback=custom_comment&type=comment'); ?>

and

<?php wp_list_comments('type=pings&callback=list_pings'); ?>

Comment: It replaced the error and now a comment is displaying. But the comment box isn't there and also when I switch off comments in the individual post through screen options, it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help so far